# Is it possible to use Appery to access data from Neo4J Graph Database?

Tags: rest, api, neo4j, graph-databases, appery.io

I have a web application that has to be linked with a graph database (Neo4J). Is it possible to read or write data to Neo4J using Appery?

I have chosen Appery because I am a beginner when it comes to databases and Appery seems to be easy in using REST API, as well as there is a free trial.

Feedback would be highly helpful. Thanks in advance.

Edit: I am aware that Neo4J uses Cypher queries. I would like to know if Appery supports Cypher as well.

Side note: The reason I am asking the question here without trying it out is because I dont have an active DB and my application is private due to my company's security policy

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do that as long as Neo4J database has a REST API. If it does, then you can make calls to it from an Appery app (from Server Code or API Express). Hope this helps.